# Ruby curb gem proplem in Windows 10 x64

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, curb

My main purpose is execute [this](https://gist.github.com/igrigorik/391312) ruby code in windows. For this purpose I installed curb gem to Windows 10 by using [this](http://beginrescue.blogspot.com.tr/2010/07/installing-curb-with-ruby-191-in.html) method. Although installation is compeleted without any error, I am taking these messages:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/curb-0.9.3/curb_core.so (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/curb-0.9.3/lib/curl.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/curb-0.9.3/lib/curb.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
        from ted-postrank.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

What is going wrong about it?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. I'm using mingw64 and the [Win64 - Generic](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win64) build extracted to C:\RubyDevKit\mingw64\. `gem install curb --platform=ruby -- -- --with-curl-lib="/mingw64/bin" --with-curl-include="/mingw64/include/"` works fine but `ruby -e "require 'curb'; c = Curl::Easy.new;"` throws the same error you see. C:\Ruby22\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\extensions\x64-mingw32\2.2.0\curb-0.9.3\curb_core.so definitely does exist.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using 32bit version of ruby on windows 10 as 64bit has problems with some gems.

First download 32bit ruby installer from http://rubyinstaller.org and install it.

Then
download `curl-7.27.0-devel-mingw32`, extract it in `C:/curl-7.27.0-devel-mingw32`
copy both libcurl.dll and libidn-11.dll into the Ruby bin directory.

and install:

```
gem install curb --platform=ruby -- --with-curl-lib="C:/curl-7.27.0-devel-mingw32/bin" --with-curl-include="C:/curl-7.27.0-devel-mingw32/include"
```